# Provide customers a SMS without changes

Tags: sms, twilio

I am looking up, whether there is technically a way to provide a SMS service where anytime someone sends/receives a text message, it's free for them, and the cost is on me.  Integration with twilio is a must.

E.g. if a customer's text messaging plan is only 500 txt msgs a month, and they txt my service, they still have 500 txt msgs a month on their plan.

I was kinda hoping toll free numbers worked like that, but I guess not?
https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/sms/do-mobile-users-get-charged-when-they-send-messages-to-twilio-us-toll-free-numbers

Comment: I don't think this is a relevant question for this website.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible. You will have to purchase a reseller plan from a bulk sms provider. Here is one that has a good reputation:

http://www.bulksms.com/solutions/sms-reseller.htm

Comment: thanks, I'm guessing it would work somehow with twilio?

Comment: I suppose you will need some sort of 'carrier' to send and receive messages, combined that with the Twilio API and i suppose you should be ready to go.

Comment: Uhuh so what does that mean? :).